# How to declare a variable inside a script using Javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript

I need to dynamically insert code in head section like this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var DID=256577; </script>
```

I tried the below method but it doesn't work like how I want .

```
var DID=256577;
s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = "type/javascript";
s.src = DID;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

The above code shows `<script type="text/javascript"> src=256577; </script>`
Instead I want it like this `<script type="text/javascript"> var DID=256577; </script>`

Comment: `256577` isn't a valid `src`.

Comment: "*[It] doesn't work like how I want.*" - how did you want it to work, what does it do instead?

Comment: The `src` attribute should be a Url.  You're basically creating a script tag like `<script type="text/javascript" src="256577"></script>` which clearly won't work.  You need to elaborate, and you'll probably need server-side code to do what you're asking.  It depends what you actually want.

Comment: I want it to show  <script type="text/javascript"> var DID=256577; </script> in head instead it shows <script type="text/javascript"> var src=256577; </script> .

Comment: It doesn't.  It adds script tags, like in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the contents of the `script` element as text nodes and inject them into the dynamically created `script` element:

```js
var newScript = document.createElement("script");
// New lines for the scrpit should be created as text nodes
var inlineScript = document.createTextNode("var DID = 256577; alert(DID);");

newScript.appendChild(inlineScript);   // The nodes are appended to the script
document.querySelector("head").appendChild(newScript);  // The script is appened to the document
```

Comment: I tried the code but in console i get an error that DID is not defined.

Comment: @AkashAchanta Then you did not implement the code as I've shown. As you can see, it works.